# No recibo el correo de Nodemailer, Ethereal

Tags: javascript, nodejs

El problema especificamente es que, al parecer Nodemailer envia "correctamente" el email, pero checando la bandeja del destinatario no aparece el correo, he checado el link autogenerado de Ehthereal, y me aparece que el correo se envio correctamente

Comment: Checa el spam folder?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.